# Matchcase for Wildcards

Tags: vba, excel-2007

I have two questions. Need some direction around this.

1) How does one use Matchcase while using LIKE Operator in VBA. The below code only matches to the exact form of the word. I think I'll have to use `.MatchWildcards = False` but don't know how/where to use it. 
***Eg:*** Searched for 'Texas' but this doesn't take into consideration 'texas'.

2) I only need to find the word 'Texas' and NOT 'TexasRangers'. Is there a way I can do this and how do I modify my code.

```
Sub Example()
   Dim wsh As Worksheet, i As Long, lngEndRowInv As Long
   Set wsh = ActiveSheet
   i = 2
   Lastr= wsh.Range("A" & wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   While i <= Lastr
      If (Cells(i, "F") Like "*New Orleans*") And (Cells(i, "D") Like "*Belfast*") Then
           Cells(i, "C").Value = "Deleted"
           Cells(i, "C").Font.Color = vbRed
      ElseIf Not ((Cells(i, "A") Like "*Texas*") Or (Cells(i, "A") Like "*NY*")) Then
           Cells(i, "A").Value = "Not Deleted"
        End If
        i = i + 1
      Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

`MatchWildcards` is part of the find/replace object model so it does not apply to VBA's `LIKE`

For case sensitivity, force a specific case;

```
... ucase$((Cells(i, "A")) Like "*TEXAS*"
```

If you want to see if a cell contains a whole-word whilst accounting for surrounding whitespace (something 'LIKE' cant really do) you can;

```
dim re: set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.pattern="\bTEXAS\b"
re.ignorecase=true

if re.test(Cells(i, "A")) then 
   //cell contains "TEXAS" in any case surrounded by a word boundary (white space, start/end of line).
```

Comment: Thanks @alex K. Could you show me how do I implement the 2nd point into this code. I have four searches to perform as you can see in my above code.  P.S I'm still learning these new concepts. Thanks for your time.